# How to hide/show only one submenu at a time?

Tags: jquery, html, css, show-hide

I created an `ul` menu and when I click on the `list` the submenu will show/hide. My problem is I have 2 submenus. When I click on the one, the other submenu will be also affected. How to hide/show correspond submenu only?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".sub_menu").click(function() {
    $(".sub").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.sub {
  margin: 0px;
}
.sub_menu {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sub_menu"><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li><a href="#">1</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Pages</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Shop</a> 
  </li>
  <li class="sub_menu"><a href="#">components</a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li><a href="#">3</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Features</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `$(this)` and `find()` like:

```
$(this).find(".sub").toggle();
```

Working snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".sub_menu").click(function() {
     $(this).find(".sub").toggle();
   });
 });
```

```css
.sub {
  margin: 0px;
}
.sub_menu {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sub_menu"><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li><a href="#">1</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Pages</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Shop</a> 
  </li>
  <li class="sub_menu"><a href="#">components</a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li><a href="#">3</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Features</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And yes, as @Satpal suggested, it's a better approach to bind the click event to the anchor tag, instead of the `li` element, otherwise your click will work through out the entire dropdown. Which I don't think you want.

My solution in this case is using `$(this)` and `next()`:

```
$(".sub_menu > a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).next('.sub').toggle();
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".sub_menu > a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('.sub').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.sub {
  margin: 0px;
}
.sub_menu {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sub_menu"><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li><a href="#">1</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Pages</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Shop</a> 
  </li>
  <li class="sub_menu"><a href="#">components</a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li><a href="#">3</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Features</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @lonut ya... I got it

Comment: @JIBINBJ, nice. Happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

Set the [context](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context) argument in jQuery selector.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $(".sub_menu").click(function(){
        $(".sub", this).toggle();
        // --------^------- here
    });    
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".sub_menu").click(function() {
    $(".sub", this).toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.sub {
  margin: 0px;
}
.sub_menu {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sub_menu"><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li><a href="#">1</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Pages</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Shop</a> 
  </li>
  <li class="sub_menu"><a href="#">components</a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li><a href="#">3</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Features</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

**FYI :** As per your code it would fire the event when you are clicked inside the `ul`. To avoid that either you need to prevent event bubbling or bind click event handler to the `a` tag as *@Satpal* suggested.

By preventing event bubbling up using [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $(".sub_menu").click(function(){
        $(".sub", this).toggle();
    }).find('.sub').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });    
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".sub_menu").click(function() {
    $(".sub", this).toggle();
  }).find('.sub').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
.sub {
  margin: 0px;
}
.sub_menu {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sub_menu"><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li><a href="#">1</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Pages</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Shop</a> 
  </li>
  <li class="sub_menu"><a href="#">components</a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li><a href="#">3</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Features</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `this`, i.e target element in the current element context. I would recommend you to bind click handler to `sub_menu` immediate child `anchor` 
element

```
$(".sub_menu > a").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.sub_menu').find(".sub").toggle();
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".sub_menu > a").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.sub_menu').find(".sub").toggle();
    });
});
```

```css
.sub {
    margin: 0px;
}
.sub_menu {
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="sub_menu"><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        <ul class="sub">
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Pages</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
    <li class="sub_menu"><a href="#">components</a>
        <ul class="sub">
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution

Comment: @Satpal : sorry that I misspelled your name... I think this would be the right answer :) don't know why someone dowvoted .... +1

Answer (score 2):

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
                    $(".sub_menu").click(function(){
                        $(this).find(".sub").toggle();
                    });
});
```

```css
.sub{
    margin:0px;
}
.sub_menu{
  margin:auto;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="sub_menu"><a href="#" >Portfolio</a>
      <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="#">1</a> </li>
         <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Pages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Shop</a> </li>
  <li class="sub_menu"><a href="#">components</a>
    <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="#">3</a> </li>
         <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
</ul>
```